# Expose MVC controller method as entry point from external application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

Can anyone point me in the right direction on exposing a controller method to an external application?

I have an MVC 4 web app, which an external application is going to be passing parameters to. My MVC application is then going to use these parameters to take the user through wizard type screens and ultimately return a `Boolean` to the calling external application.

I'm just not sure if I should be somehow using WCF to expose, but then I need to display the pages/views to the calling app/user.

Any help is appreciated!

thanks.

Comment: Do You know any specifics regarding that "external" application? There are multiple possible scenarios. Is that "external" app already finished? Does it have an API?

Comment: Exposing your API over MVC is likely not the best approach. Take a look at creating a WebAPI project.

Comment: Hi @GrzegorzW thanks for your response. Unfortunately I do not know anything about the external application at this time. However, I would like to cater for future apps being able to connect to it, so WCF would be preferred, if that's a possibility? The app will be passing around 6 primitive values and I just want to display (or be redirected to) the Index of the Home controller. Thanks

Comment: Hi @IanP thanks for your suggestion. With most of the foundation in place, is there a way that the existing MVC app can be converted to a WebAPI, or can be included into the existing app?

Comment: Ideally there's no logic in your controllers, so it should be very easy to add a WebAPI project to your solution. Does that make sense?

Comment: @IanP Unfortunately, I have little experience with WebAPI. I will be reading up on this, but can you tell me - If I add a WebAPI project to my solution, will this give me the ability to expose methods from within my MVC project?

Comment: You can add ApiController classes inside Your MVC project without a problem. I would suggest creating a separate Area for those Controllers. ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET WebAPI can easily co-exist inside the same project. But I see no need for WebAPI in Your situation.

Comment: Thanks @GrzegorzW I've been looking at these ApiControllers online and this certainly holds some value to what I'm looking for. However, one thing I am unsure of, is how the external application is going to display MY application. When the button is clicked on the external app, would we use JSON or something to redirect to my page? Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

If your calling app is also a web App you can simply do a redirect from your calling app to your MVC app.

```
return Redirect("{Your MVC Controller URL}")
```

then when the second app completes you simply redirect back to the original caller, with your bool value as a parameter.

Comment: Hi @theDarse unfortunately, the calling application is not an MVC application. At this time I'm not sure what it is, as it is also in development. Do you know of any way this can be exposed via WCF?

Comment: hmm well you could do a Process.Start("{Controller URL}")  This will start your mvc project and run you through the process, then at the end you call your wcf service to return your value, i don't think you can directly return the value to the first app this way however, you will need to store the response and check it from the first app

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, i suggest you to implement a double tracked solution. First the user gets (parametrized) redirected to your entry/landing view or page. After the user finishes the wizard styled screens you can redirect the user to the external application if needed (parametrized with the boolean value of wizard result). But the user can close her/his browser window. So, in addition to this you should notify independently the external application with the booleand value of wizard result. This you can do with whatever method you like.. WCF, simple HTTP etc.